# Audacious uses volume control when I've configured the media hotkeys

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, volume-control, audacious

Using Ubuntu 12.10 on an Asus u30sd.

I've managed to get Audacious to recognize my laptop's media keys (fn-play, etc) for playback, but it also hijacks the volume hotkey, so I can't change the system volume when using Audacious.  Changing the volume only changes the Audacious volume.

Anyone have ideas how I can have both?  I want the hotkeys for play, next track, etc, but I don't want to control Audacious volume with my volume keys (which are also Fn-keys).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while to think it through but the issue is the multimedia hotkeys plugin. Simply remove the volume up/down and mute entries from the plugin, and normal system volume regains focus of the multimedia keys while still allowing play/pause next previous functionality.

File -> Preferences (or if in winamp view, right click and select preferences)

Click on Plugins

Select the "General" tab.

CLick on "GLobal Hotkeys" plugin and click Preferences

Click the red circle with a line through it beside each of volume up, volume down and mute.

For completeness, I also removed the individual entries for play and stop, keeping only the combined pause/resume option, as it worked better on my laptop that way.